# how can I show my "ztable" when I use "knit to HTML" in R?

Tags: r, html-table

I am having a problem with my ztable, 
I want to knit my Rmarkdown file to HTML but I cannot find a way to display the table I created with ztable:

```
z=ztable(loucaste) %>% makeHeatmap(palette = "Blues") %>% print(caption="Table 2.)
```

[image]

I tried to set

```
options(ztable.table="html")
```

and put this at the beginning as I read somewhere else

```
output: html_document
header-includes: \usepackage{colortbl}
```

but it doesn't work when I knit to HTML. My intention was to create a sort of formatting table similar to the ones made on excel and ztable looks like the only way.

Comment: I tried `matrix(1:100, nrow = 10) %>% as.data.frame() %>% ztable() %>% makeHeatmap()` in a Rmarkdown document and it knitted to HTML without any problems.  Perhaps include information about your ztable version, operating system, R version; or a more complete example (minimal complete Rmd code).

Comment: I tried your example and there is no table in my html ! I have Rstudio Version 1.1.463 , I am using windows and the just installed ztable using this code #install.packages("ztable")
#if(!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")
#devtools::install_github("cardiomoon/ztable") then I called the two packages library("ztable")
library("magrittr")

Comment: Maybe try `ztable` from CRAN, not github. My version is 0.2.0.

Comment: I tried to install both ztable and magrittr again with install.packages() but it is still not appearing in the html file..

Comment: Your YAML lines don't make sense for HTML output:  they are for PDF output using LaTeX. Use `output: html_document`, and skip the `header-includes:` line.

Comment: ops, I wrote pdf, but in reality I was using html_document, I tried to skip the header includes but it is still not working, so strange!

Comment: Aha. Now that I look more carefully, I'm getting the table in a separate HTML document but not in the knitted report. More investigation required!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this minimal Rmd. The key seems to be `options(ztable.type = "html")` and in the chunk that generates the table, `r results='asis'`

If that works for you, substitute your code in the appropriate place *i.e.* `ztable(loucaste) %>% makeHeatmap(palette = "Blues") %>% print(caption="Table 2.)`.

````
---
title: "ztable"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)


library(ztable)
library(magrittr)

options(ztable.type = "html")
```

## R Markdown

```{r results='asis'}
matrix(1:100, nrow = 10) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  ztable() %>% 
  makeHeatmap() %>% 
  print(caption = "table 2")
```
````

Comment: it finally works! thank you very much for your help, my mistake was to put options(ztable.type = "html") before creating the table, while I had to put it in the r setup as you did.